# XQuery, check element empty?

Tags: xquery

How can i check if a node has no text in it? I can use string($node)=""  because a node can be like this

```
<node>              </node>
```

what i mean that, it can contain spaces but no text in it??

Answer (score 1):

We got caught by this very thing where spaces and line breaks where causing us some grief when checking to see if a node really had text. In the end we created a function that examines the text nodes of an element and we check to see if any of those text nodes contain any word characters. Here's what it looks like:

```
some $child in $node/text() satisfies (fn:matches($child, "\w+"))
```

If one of the child text nodes has any word characters, we defined that as having text and of course if it has no text nodes or has text nodes that don't have word characters, we defined that as not having text.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `fn:normalize-space` function.